# FileReference.save() through javascript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, actionscript, filereference

I have a javascript function that processes data and generates a file to be downloaded. The main browsers have a native function or allow using the `download` attribute on the `A` tag as a way to save this file on the client's disk. IE 9 and 8 (which I must still support) doesn't. So it came to my mind I could use flash to do the work in these cases (`ExternalInterface.addCallback`), however it looks like I will need to place an extra button to do so (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302164), isn't there a way to contour this and call `FileReference.save` without a click?

Comment: But you said that you have an A tag? Why not use the click on the link?

Comment: Each browser behaves a different way for downloads, the `download` attribute allows me to set the default file name, at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope no way. This is a security restriction in the flash player.