# AS3 call function inside loader event function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, events, listener

I have a problem to call a function inside a conditional in another function. I've tried it and it works perfectly but it depends on where the call is made.

Process: I have the `checkCode();` function that is called when a form is completed and sent.

```
private function checkCode():void {
    var url = "checktrue.php";
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var urlvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    urlvars.codeVar = formattedCode;
    urlreq.data = urlvars;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed); //Completed function
    status.text = "calling loader";
    loader.load(urlreq);
}
```

When php is complete, "completed" is called and:

```
private function completed(event:Event = null):void {
    var loader2: URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var checked:String = loader2.data.checked;
    var codetrue:String = loader2.data.codetrue;

    if(checked == "1" || codetrue == null || codetrue == "") {
        trace("WRONG");
    }
    else{
        download(); //download function
        trace("ok");
    }
}
```

Here I get the php vars and check if they are valid to call the `download()` function.

```
public function download():void {
    req = new URLRequest(proxy + filename);
    file = new FileReference();

    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    file.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
    file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    file.download(req, "file.zip");
```

}

It is possible this function cannt be called from the "completed" loader function?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Which of two traces you get - `"WRONG"` or `"ok"`?

Comment: The problem is the download() isnt executed @Andrey Popov

Comment: Do you get the `ok` trace at all?

Comment: I can test it online, so Im using `ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "download");` and I can see the log in chrome. Thank you

Comment: can I share the code with you? maybe in jsfiddle @Andrey Popov

Comment: @AndreyPopov I think i see the problem, `file.download(req, "file.zip");` doesnt work in the place where it is located...

Comment: That's another problem, because the function is executing. Try logging out the file path and check if it exists. I'm not sure if it should be relative to the html or the swf, I guess the first :|

Comment: @AndreyPopov If I put this line in another place works fine :/ ie: after click function/event of the form-button... Sorry What do you mean by logging out the file path? Thanks

Comment: Insteada of `file.zip` I think you should write down proper file path :)

Comment: this file.zip is the name of the file to download, the url or path is in another line.

Comment: Is possible `download()`function of "fileReference" works only in a button event?

Comment: It sure is! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301839/flexs-filereference-save-can-only-be-called-in-a-user-event-handler-how-ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the download function in another button for the correct use. Or create your own event.