# Should I workaround Flex security error 2176

Tags: actionscript-3, security, apache-flex

I got the following error:

`Error #2176: Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, 
may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click 
or button press.`

I found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301839/flexs-filereference-save-can-only-be-called-in-a-user-event-handler-how-ca) and the short explanation of the problem is:

`Adobe does this as a sort of security measure to ensure users are the 
ones messing with files rather than potentially harmful code`

However this thread doesn't answered my questions and that's why I am asking here:

1) Is there a good reason for me getting this error and is it really a security issue (and if so - maybe I shouldn't workaround it?).

2) What are the potential consequences if I do my workaround (I am asking because obviously Adobe decided that it shouldn't be workaround-ed)

Comment: We don't have many clairvoyants over here, you'll have to show what you are doing to receive that error in the first place, and explain how you're planning to workaround it.

Comment: I will use the workaround with the two event listeners for the events MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP mentioned in the other thread. 


I am getting the error when I manually dispatch an MouseEvent.CLICK on a button that invokes action that goes trough the files.

Maybe I wasn't clear enough - my concern is whether it is a good idea to workaround something that obviously isn't supposed to be workaround-ed and how this can do any harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't try to work around it.  Flash isn't allowed to download arbitrary files to your hard drive for some *very good reasons*.

Instead, just use `FileReference.download()`.  The [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) talk more about it.  Then you can trigger the download on the user's click.